# Django admin double filter reverse foreign key lookup

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm trying to do a reverse look up in an admin form for two different fields, one parent of each other. the idea is I've got the following Hierarchy of dropdown menus.

> Area
>
> Linea (filtered by Area) Fk = Area
>
> Sensor (filtered by Linea) Fk = Linea.
>
> add sensor details.

Right now I'm trying modifying the ModelForm for adding sensors by adding self reffering filters for the foreign keys and then making a ModelAdmin. Like so:

```
class SensorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SensorAsignado, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Linea'].queryset = Linea.objects.filter(no_de_linea = self.instance.linea)
        self.fields['Area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(Linea.objects.filter(no_de_linea = self.instance.linea))

class SensorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SensorForm
```

The idea is to have two fields, Linea and area, Linea is filtered by Area, and Sensor is filtered by Linea.

Here's a snippet of the models:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    description = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.area_nom
    
# rack del cual fue sacada la pieza    
class Linea(models.Model):
    linea_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area')
    description = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.linea_nom
    
# sensor del cual se sacó la lectura
class SensorAsignado(models.Model):
    sensor_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    linea = models.ForeignKey('Linea')
    sensor_tipo = models.ForeignKey('TipoDeSensor')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sensor_nom
```

Thanks a lot in advance and hope you all have a good day.